# Create a panel with label of today's date that changes content according today's data

Tags: java, swing, date

Here is my sample GUI Draft I just wanted to create a panel with the corresponding day and date today that changes its content for todays schedule.

Is it possible to create a panel with label of Day and Date Today that changes content according to what date today and what data are for today?

[image]

Comment: *"Is it possible to create a panel with label of Day and Date Today that changes content according to what date today and what data are for today?"* Yes.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. For more info look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It’s a very broad question, not really suited for the Stack Overflow format, sorry. I also believe that the individual pieces of a solution — like getting today’s date and showing data in a GUI — have been covered very many times, both on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, so your search engine should be able to get you a very long way. If some detail ends up being troublesome for you, your in a good position to ask a question that will fit the Stack Overflow format much better.

Comment: One warning for your search: You will encounter many sites saying that you should use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` for the date and for formatting it. While once true, it isn’t anymore, so skip such sites quickly. For getting today’s date in a string use something like `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a simple sample `JFrame` with a label showing today’s date:

```
public class FrameWithTodaysDate extends JFrame {

    JLabel todayLabel = new JLabel();

    public FrameWithTodaysDate() {
        super("Day Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setTodaysDate();
        add(todayLabel);

        pack();
    }

    private void setTodaysDate() {
        String today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"))
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL));
        todayLabel.setText(today);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameWithTodaysDate().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

On my computer today it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Please fill in your desired time zone where I put Asia/Tokyo.

If you need to update the date in the frame when a new day begins (at midnight), let’s use a timer as Sergiy Medvynskyy suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941143/create-a-panel-with-label-of-todays-date-that-changes-content-according-todays#comment86898199_49941143). I am rewriting `setTodaysDate`:

```
private void setTodaysDate() {
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
    LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate();
    String todayString = today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL));
    todayLabel.setText(todayString);

    int millisUntilTomorrow = (int) ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(now,
            today.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(zone));
    Timer nextUpdate = new Timer(millisUntilTomorrow, e -> setTodaysDate());
    nextUpdate.setRepeats(false);
    nextUpdate.start();
}
```

It may look a little bit complicated because I am taking summer time (DST) and the like into account: a day may be, say, 23 or 25 hours and it may not begin at 00:00.

For the method to work we need

```
    private ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo");
```

That should be it.